# trigger.Once() metadata needed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Hi guys simple question for experienced guys. 
I have a spark job reading files under a path.
I wanted to use structured streaming even when the source is not really a stream but just a folder with a bunch of files in it.

My question can I use trigger.Once() for this. And if yes how do I make trigger.Once recognizing new files as such.

I tried it out on my laptop and the first run reads everything but when I start the job again files written in the mean time are not recognized and processed at all.

my method looks like this:

```
def executeSql(spark:SparkSession):Unit ={

    val file = "home/hansherrlich/input_event/"

    val df  = spark.readStream.format("json").schema(getStruct).load("home/hansherrlich/some_event/")

    val out =    df.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.Once()).format("json").option("path","home/hansherrlich/some_event_processed/").start()

    out.processAllAvailable()
    out.stop()
    //out.awaitTermination()
    println("done writing")

}
```

Comment: if reading from files this seems only to work if files where written Delta by  Data Bricks.

Answer (score 0):

if reading from files this seems only to work if files where written Delta by  Data Bricks.